# Polling Continuously from a SQS queue on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a java class that connects to an SQS queue and I would like it to respond to messages that are sent to the SQS queue. Is that possible without running the java class continuously, sending receiveMessageRequests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, its not possible. SQS requires you to poll to see if there are messages waiting for you.

If you could uses SNS instead of SQS you could have messages pushed to you instead.